# NetBeans doesn't output certain ASCII characters

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying to print ASCII characters, but in the output I only see a little box. For example, ASCII 179 is a `|` character, but it doesn't print. Instead, it prints:

[image]

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int a[] {179,180,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,217,218,32};

char b = a[2];

std::cout << b;   
return 0;
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Note, when I use this code, the output prints the characters correctly:

```
std::cout << "┐"
```

But if I use the ASCII character, it prints a box instead.

---

**Edit**: To add... even when I output the characters to Notepad, I get the same result.

Comment: have you tried to print an alphabetical character (like a simple "a")?

Comment: I tried printing "|" as a string and it printed, but through ascii char it didn't. Instead it printed that box. and if I copy that boxy and paste it to stackoverflow, it is replaced by this character �. Note- I did print a simple 'a' and it worked fine, everything works except special characters that I have in my int array.

Comment: in fact, you are getting char at a[2] which is not 179 but 191, according to ascii table 191 is "┐" That's maybe why a box is printed, this char may not be in your default font

Comment: @Supamiu sorry I forgot to mention, I tested all of those characters in the array, all of them print a box. I edited my question to note that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be an encoding issue. NetBeans by default, is not printing data with UTF-8 encoding.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://peterfeatherstone.com/set-default-encoding-utf-8-netbeans/) to change NetBeans' default encoding.

Comment: I followed the steps point to point but the result is the same. Why am I able to print the symbol as a string but not as a character?

Comment: did you try to run the code in a windows/linux console?

Comment: I'm running the code in netbeans, windows 7. I don't know how to run it any other way, I'm quiet new to c and c++.

Comment: try to do `std::cout << char(a[0])`

Comment: That prints a box also.

Comment: what about doing `std::cout << itoa(a[0])`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86696/discussion-between-almost-a-beginner-and-supamiu).

Comment: Still seeking answer as everything I have tried failed.